# How can I configure Angular Router to still update browser URL in case of error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

When in development with Angular (v4) using Angular Cli, I would love to have the following behavior:

1. I load load a certain route and an error occurs
2. The Browser URL is changed/updated before the error is reported
3. I fix the error in the source file and via Angular CLI my browser is refreshed with the intended URL

Currently when I load my targeted route and an error occurs, the browser URL seems to jump to the root URL.

Back in the AngularJS 1.x + UI Router days, this was the default behavior. I like the `old` behavior as I don't have to do any navigation as long as I develop/fix one particular page.

Is there a way to configure Angular v4 that way?

Comment: do you want to just update the URL? or fallback to another page on error+ update url

Comment: @SibiRaj Just update the URL. If my route goes to `/my-route`, then `my-route` should be in my browser bar, even in case of an error (e.g. template error, component error etc.)

Answer (score 0):

in your error handler route to a desired component

Either

route

```
{ 
  component: FallbackComponent, 
  path: "fallback" 
}
```

logic

```
try{
// some logic
}
catch{
 this.router.navigate(['/fallback'])
}
```

or

depending on how you've implemented to the logic you can pass in a bogus route and have a [wildcard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#wildcard) route and handle the error in any way and have a fall back route

```
{ 
  component: FallBackComponent, 
  path: "**" // this catches bogus routes and redirects (put at the end)
}
```

or

implement a [routeguard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - But I don't want to navigate to a _fallback URL_. I want that the originally intended target URL is showing in my browser in case of an error. Unfortunately that is not the case. So if I want to go to `/this-url-causes-an-exception`, the browser should not revert to the root URL in case of an exception but still show `/this-url-causes-an-exception` after logging the exception.

Comment: You should post some code. it sounds like you simply need to prevent the navigation upon error.

Or - If the error happens after navigating, either try to determine if the error will be caused before navigating 

Or - in the try-catch block use `constructor(private _location: Location)`...`this._location.back();` which will return to your previous url.